# How to use file path present in one try block in another in java

Tags: java, try-catch

Can someone please let me know how can I use the file path that is present in one try block in another block? Below is my code:

```
    try
    {

        Path file = Paths.get("testing.txt");
        byte[] bytesFromFile = Files.readAllBytes(file);

        String textFromFile = new String(bytesFromFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        String s = String.format(textFromFile, "12");


        Path file1 = Files.write(file, s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

        System.out.println(file1); --> **Contains file path and I want to use this in next try block.**
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ClassLoader loader = TestSpecification.class.getClassLoader();


                   input = loader.getSystemResources(file1); --> **It is throwing me an error.**


    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `input`? It's not declared anywhere in your code. Also, the code does not compile because `ClassLoader.getSystemResources(...)` does not have an overload that would accept a `Path` (the type of `file1`) as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution may help you :

```
Path file1 = null;
try {
    Path file = Paths.get("testing.txt");
    byte[] bytesFromFile = Files.readAllBytes(file);
    String textFromFile = new String(bytesFromFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String s = String.format(textFromFile, "12");
    file1 = Files.write(file, s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    System.out.println(file1); --> **Contains file path and I want to use this in next try block.**
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    ClassLoader loader = TestSpecification.class.getClassLoader();
    input = loader.getSystemResources(file1); --> **It is throwing me an error.**

} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: when I initialize Path file1 = null; I'm getting issue in the second try block at line input = loader.getSystemResources(file1); It says "The method getSystemResources(String) in the type ClassLoader is not applicable for the arguments (Path)"

Comment: This is because Path is a type and it differs from string. I am not shure about this but I guess you could call file1.toString() which should give you the file path as a string

Comment: This error is saying that .getSystemResources(file1) method accepts String  parameter while you are passing it a Path type value. Pass the String format resource name to this method

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just an addendum to the answer by Rahul. If the answer by him was helpfull mark his answer as the accepted answer and not mine !

The first question was answered by Rahul, if you want to know in depth why this is working maybe you could google java scope introduction and I guess you get many adresses( for example I found this http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2iN3TO5qOQ ).

The short answer is that every opening `{` starts a new scope for variables and the scope is ended when `}` is reached.

The second error you encounter is because this

```
 input = loader.getSystemResources(file1);
```

expects a String variable like "C:\somefile" but you pass a Path variable into it which the method isn't expecting nor understanding.